# NSNotificationCenter sending selector to the wrong instance

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nsnotificationcenter

I am getting a very strange error while using NSNotificationCenter.

In my PersistentStack class, a subclass of NSObject, I am subscribing to three notifications:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "storesDidChange:", name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "storesWillChange:", name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges:", name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, object: nil)
```

When these selectors are called however as a response to a notification being posted, I get a variety of different errors such as

```
[__NSCFArray storesDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166197f0
[NSFetchedResultsController storesDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I am confused as to why other objects are getting the selector, not the object I am registering it to.

Any insight/help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

-Steven

EDIT: More code for context.

AppDelegate

```
var persistentStack : PersistentStack { 
    return PersistentStack(storeURL: self.storeURL(), modelURL: self.modelURL())
}
```

PersistentStack

```
init(storeURL : NSURL, modelURL : NSURL) {

    super.init()

    self.storeURL = storeURL
    self.modelURL = modelURL
    setupManagedObjectContext()

}    

func setupManagedObjectContext() {

    self.managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    self.managedObjectContext!.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    self.managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel!)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "storesDidChange:", name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "storesWillChange:", name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges:", name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, object: nil)

    var error : NSError?

    self.managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator?.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType
        , configuration: nil, URL: self.storeURL, options: [NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : "iCloudStore"], error: &error)

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSNotificationCenter` doesn't retain it's targets, this leads to errors where it will send a message to an object that has been deallocated. It sounds like you are not removing the object from `NSNotificationCenter` on `deinit` and another object (NSArray in this case) just happens to be occupying that space and receiving the messages intended for the now released object.

To remove the object from `NSNotificationCenter`:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
```

I would place that in your deinit and put a breakpoint on it to see if that is the case.

Comment: Will removing the observer mean I cannot get the notifications anymore?

Comment: Yes. The object needs to stick around to receive notifications.

Comment: I am currently creating a PersistentStack object in my AppDelegate and leaving it there, is there any way I can prevent it from being deinitialized?

Comment: Make it a property. Update your question with more code for better feedback from me or others.

Comment: Updated with some more code, let me know if that helps. Thanks again!

Comment: I solved it, it was with how I was declaring my property in my AppDelegate. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your `PersistentStack` instance is released by ARC. We can't help more without seeing more code (especially the code where `PersistentStack` instance is created and kept).

Comment: I am currently creating a PersistentStack object in my AppDelegate and leaving it there, if that makes any difference.